# ajax progress bar zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, progress-bar, action

i use zend farmework.i have 2 ajax.one of my ajax proccess a file to db and take several minutes.and the other one get the status of first action and get percentage of first ajax.
i have tow action for this tow ajax.the first one call a "model class" in zend.my "model class" have property that keep the status.this property start from 0 to 100.
i want to get that property in my secound action.
for example i call this action in every 10 secound and get the status.
how can i do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file processes line-by-line into the database, have your first action create a Zend_Session_Namespace to store two values:

1. The total number of lines in the file, and
2. the number of lines processed so far (which will update as each line processes.)

Your second action will then access the Zend_Session_Namespace and return the two values. You can then use Javascript to plug the values into a progress bar plugin or however you want to visually represent that information. If you need to use asynchronous javascript to upload the file and check on the progress of its processing, look into [PHP Session Upload Progress](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) -- that way you could have one progress bar for the upload and another for the processing of that file (though many browsers indicate upload progress in their native status bars.)